# Run WinCE application

Tags: windows-mobile

I am working on VC++ for WinCE application development. I want to know that, once, I have compiled the project, how to see the output of it on PC ? Can I run the application without the hardware (The development board on which WinCE is loaded) on the computer or I must need the hardware device for it ?

Answer (score 1):

Your binary will be compiled for a different OS (Windows CE) and potentially a different processor.  That means that your desktop OS will have no ability to execute the application.

There are some emulators that ship with the development tools (Windows Mobile, Pocket PC, etc) and there's even a [standalone emulator](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=A6F6ADAF-12E3-4B2F-A394-356E2C2FB114&displaylang=en) and [Emulator BSP](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/barrybo/archive/2006/03/15/552045.aspx) for creating your own; you can run one of them on your desktop machine and then have that emulator run your code.  That might work, depending on your target CPU (Microsoft's DeviceEmulator emulates ARM, so you must compile for ARM).

So the short answer is no, you can't run it on your desktop directly, but if you use an emulator, you might be able to use the app (depending on if it uses non-emulated hardware or not).